# Google Search API - Only returning 4 results

Tags: python, google-search, google-search-api

After much experimenting and googling, the following Python code successfully calls Google's Search APi - but only returns 4 results: after reading the Google Search API docs, I thought the 'start=' would return additional results: but this not happen.

Can anyone give pointers? Thanks.

Python code:

```
/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import simplejson

query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : 'site:example.com'})
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s&start=50' \
  % (query)
search_results = urllib.urlopen(url)
json = simplejson.loads(search_results.read())
results = json['responseData']['results']
for i in results:
  print i['title'] + ": " + i['url']
```

Answer (score 2):

The start option doesn't give you more results, it just moves you forward that many results. Think of the results as a queue. Starting at 50 will give you results 50, 51, 52, and 53.

With this you can get more results by starting every 4th result:

```
import urllib
import simplejson

num_queries = 50*4 
query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : 'example'})
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query

for start in range(0, num_queries, 4):
    request_url = '{0}&start={1}'.format(url, start)
    search_results = urllib.urlopen(request_url)
    json = simplejson.loads(search_results.read())
    results = json['responseData']['results']
    for i in results:
        print i['title'] + ": " + i['url']
```

Comment: somehow, ``search_results`` is always empty. why is this?