# python google search API - not giving correct results

Tags: python, google-search-api

```
^
|
| this question DOES NOT HAVE an answer yet!
```

I am trying to do google search from python script.

```
xing = "site:xing.com inurl:profile intext:Systemadministrator AND UNIX AND Hamburg"
query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : xing } )
response = urllib.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read()
import json as m_json
json = m_json.loads ( response )
results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
print len(results)
```

the problem is, it is giving  me only 4 results. If i paste the search string in google, it is finding more than 100 results. what am i doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

i changed the code to this:

```
import urllib
import django.utils import simplejson
num_queries = 50*4 
xing = "site:xing.com inurl:profile intext:Systemadministrator AND UNIX AND Hamburg"
query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : xing})
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query

for start in range(0, num_queries, 4):
    request_url = '{0}&start={1}'.format(url, start)
    search_results = urllib.urlopen(request_url)
    json = simplejson.loads(search_results.read())
    results = json['responseData']['results']
return HttpResponse(search_results)
```

i am receiving no data. `search_results` is empty. why is this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506173/google-search-api-only-returning-4-results?rq=1

Comment: @Haidro: Not just related, but duplicate.

Comment: @JohnY Wouldn't let me close as dupe because the question doesn't have any upvoted answers

Comment: @Haidro, the Link you gave doesnot provide also correct answer. i commented a question there also. could you pls take a look?